# cannot conver t argument 1 from 'v8::Local<v8::Value>' to 'const v8::String::Utf8Value

Tags: visual-studio, node-modules, node-sass

I am trying to run two of the below commands :

```
npm install
npm audit fix
```

in VS Code when the below error is reported.

```
error C2664: 'v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(const v8::String::Utf8Value &)': cannot conver
t argument 1 from 'v8::Local<v8::Value>' to 'const v8::String::Utf8Value &
```

Any help to resolve this is much appreciated!!

Comment: What happens if you run it from the command line outside VSCode?

Comment: I tried running the above commands from VS Code as well as the Command Prompt.Both gave the same error.

Comment: "npm audit fix" did the job for me

Answer (score 14):

Change Nodejs to version 10.19.0, node-sass not working with Nodejs 12.

Comment: Using Node version 11.15 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

[This](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2632#issuecomment-486186423)
described the issue, and
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57899840/5765678)
somewhat-hidden post helped me fix the buggy node-sass .cpp file to where I was able to proceed, using the version I wanted to.

I edited the node-sass `create_string.cpp` file, changing `v8::String::Utf8Value string(value);` to `v8::String::Utf8Value string(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), value);`.

Comment: I tried many things, only this solutions worked! kudos!

Comment: There is no `create_string.cpp` unless you do what the linked post says: `npm install` and, when you see `node-sass` logs in the console, terminate it by pressing Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 4):

Change Nodejs version to node-sass@4.12.0 for nodeJS 12.

For more help go through this [DOC](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2632)

Comment: This solved my issue rather than downgrading nodeJS. I was getting error with node-sass version as 4.11.0 , changing to 4.12.0 resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Highly Appreciated man, I got this issue and it took almost 2 days to find this solution.