# Mouse wheel tilt vs. scroll in JavaScript, scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, html5-canvas, mouseevent

Some computer mice have a [scroll wheel that can be tilted left and right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_wheel#:%7E:text=some%20mice%20can%20scroll%20horizontally%20as%20well%20as%20vertically%2C%20using%20a%20tilting%20scroll-wheel).

This allows to navigate the time dimension in [Google's piano roll app](https://musiclab.chromeexperiments.com/Piano-Roll/) (code is [here](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/chrome-music-lab/tree/master/pianoroll)).

I have the following goals:

1. Make the piano roll vertical rather than horizontal. Here is an image with vertical bars scrolling in a different app, just as an example:

[image]

2. Allow the usual vertical mousewheel scrolling to navigate the time dimension (instead of the mousewheel left/right tilt like currently).

I achieved the first goal by replacing

```
this.context.translate(-offset * 2, 0);
```

[here](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/chrome-music-lab/blob/master/pianoroll/app/roll/Score.js#L210) by

```
this.context.translate(0, offset * 2);
```

and by swapping `left` with `top` and `height` with `width` and changing some signs [here](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/chrome-music-lab/blob/master/pianoroll/app/roll/Note.js#L66-L70) (codebase [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/guw5y2who8kvtsl/AABS6ek1Zl-KwswF9f_5gZ6ta?dl=1)).

However, the time dimension still responds to mousewheel left/right tilt instead of usual vertical mousewheel scrolling. It might have something to do with [the file Scroll.js](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/chrome-music-lab/blob/master/pianoroll/app/roll/Scroll.js). I tried replacing `scrollLeft` by `scrollTop` and similar things, but that broke the currently okay functionality. Any hints how the info about horizontal scrolling gets passed on?

(For getting the code to run: `npm install`, [solutions to error C2664](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971154/cannot-conver-t-argument-1-from-v8localv8value-to-const-v8stringutf). Then call `node_modules/.bin/webpack -p` from the `pianoroll` directory. Open `index.html`. To get sound: click the piano symbol first, then click play.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `roll.scss`, replace

```
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
```

by

```
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
```

Without this modification, `scrollTop` wasn't changing.