# NPM - node sass error when trying to install dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, node-sass

Getting a bunch of warnings and errors when installing my dependencies with node 13.1.0.

> c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=binding' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DBUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' -I/Users/marinosony/.node-gyp/13.1.0/include/node -I/Users/marinosony/.node-gyp/13.1.0/src -I/Users/marinosony/.node-gyp/13.1.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/marinosony/.node-gyp/13.1.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/marinosony/.node-gyp/13.1.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/marinosony/.node-gyp/13.1.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/marinosony/.node-gyp/13.1.0/deps/v8/include -I../../nan -I../src/libsass/include  -Os -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++1y -stdlib=libc++ -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=c++11 -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o ../src/create_string.cpp
>   ../src/create_string.cpp:17:25: **error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'v8::String::Utf8Value'**
>     v8::String::Utf8Value string(value);
>                           ^      ~~~~~
>   /Users/marinosony/.node-gyp/13.1.0/include/node/v8.h:3064:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
>         'v8::Local' to 'const v8::String::Utf8Value' for 1st argument
>       Utf8Value(const Utf8Value&) = delete;
>       ^
>   /Users/marinosony/.node-gyp/13.1.0/include/node/v8.h:3057:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was
>         provided
>       Utf8Value(Isolate* isolate, Local obj);
>       ^
>   1 error generated.
>   make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o] Error 1
>   gyp ERR! build error 
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/marinosony/Desktop/SofiaPaySys/SofiaAPI/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
>   gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
>   gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.1.0/bin/node" "/Users/marinosony/Desktop/SofiaPaySys/SofiaAPI/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
>   gyp ERR! cwd /Users/marinosony/Desktop/SofiaPaySys/SofiaAPI/node_modules/node-sass
>   gyp ERR! node -v v13.1.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
>   gyp ERR! not ok

- node version: **13.1.0**
- node-sass version: **4.13.1**

Comment: What version of **node** and **node-sass** you are using? Please provide it as well.

Comment: node v13.1.0  & node-sass 4.13.1. Maybe do i need to downgrade node-sass to 4.13.0 ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yarn - Node Sass does not yet support my current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973930/yarn-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-my-current-environment)

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. Apparently , i had to downgrade both node and node-sass version.

Comment: i had the same issue with node v16, downgraded to node v14 and it works fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer. i had to downgrade my node version to  10.16.0 and my node-sass version to 4.12.0. 
[Yarn - Node Sass does not yet support my current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973930/yarn-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-my-current-environment)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: just a `npm update` worked for me

Comment: If you are using homebrew, the following worked for me:


brew install node@12
brew unlink node
brew link node@12

Or whatever version you need to downgrade to..

Comment: downgrading node is always not a solution though one who is willing to upgrade the node and its components, just because of one package, shouldn't dowgrade. This is a workaround and not a solution

Answer (score 0):

This is version problem try to install it with --unsafe-perm

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Comment: let me know if you steal have problem..

Comment: it's not work. i've got the same issue "error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'v8::String::Utf8Value' v8::String::Utf8Value string(value);"

Comment: have you tried npm install node-sass ??

Comment: Yes. i've got no problem with "npm install node-sass" installation . My trouble come when i try to install some package with npm. Actually this come when i try to install "h5bp" package with npm.